# How to insert a promise into a block of code inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, promise

I have some code here, the idea is to create a ranking on an index based on the prices and amount of nutrients of some foods within a Wix database:

```
function calculate() {
var array = [];
wixData.query('Food').find().then(res => {
        for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
          const item = res.items[i];

          const nutrientOfAmount = item[nutrientId];
          let grams = Number(item.grams);
          let price = Number(item.price);

          var index = (nutrientOfAmount * grams) / price;

          array.push(index);
          if (Number.isNaN(index)) {
                array.pop()
           }

           array.sort((a, b) => a - b);
           array.reverse();

           if (array[0] === index) {
             $w('#text1').text = item.food;
             $w('#text2').text = `${index}`;
           }
           if (array[1] === index) {
             $w('#text3').text = item.food;
             $w('#text4').text = `${index}`;
           }
           if (array[2] === index) {
             $w('#text5').text = item.food;
             $w('#text6').text = `${index}`;
           }
     }
 })
}

$w('#button').onClick(() => calculate());
```

only the if cascade is running inside the for so it returns several foods in the #text but none is actually the array[0], array[1] and array[2], the for should run until the if (Number.isNaN (index)) {array.pop()}, and array.sort((a, b) => a - b); should remain on hold until the for has gone through all the foods.

(Note: I cannot place the if cascade outside the for because the ranking takes into account more information, which in this case is inside the for, it will have to be something related to promises)

I'm trying to run two sets of code inside a for loop inside a function, with the second part executing only after the first one completes

Comment: Please edit your question and remove the 'java' tag.

Comment: Downvoted for not removing invalid tag even after the request

Answer (score 1):

You try to sort and output your results inside your `for` loop without waiting it complete. That creates some mess. Just calculate the results and then use them:

```
async function calculate(nutrientId) {

  let items = await wixData.query('Food').find();
  
  // first calculate ranks
  
  items.forEach(item => item.rank = item[nutrientId] * item.grams / item.price);
  // you don't need reverse() just swap a and b
  items = items
    .filter(item => !isNaN(item.rank))
    .sort((a, b) => b.rank - a.rank)
  ;
  
  // do your output
  
  for(let i = 0, index = 1; i < items.length; i++, index += 2){
       $w('#text' + index).text = item.food;
       $w('#text' + (index + 1)).text = `${i + 1}`;
  }

}

$w('#button').onClick(() => calculate(nutrientId));
```